# Jquery help creating ajax request

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create an ajax request where the URL is the form on submit.

My Jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('.menuitem input:checkbox').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
          type:'get',
          url:form.submit();,
          data:form.serialize(),
          success:function(msg){
            $('#formcontent').html(msg);
          }
        })
    })
    $('input:submit').hide();

    $('.menuitem input:checkbox').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('div.hidediv').removeClass("hidediv");
    } 
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.menuitem input:checkbox').change(function() {
    // fetch the form containing the checkbox whose value
    // has just changed so that we could infer its action and method
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: form.attr('method'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(msg) {
            $('#formcontent').html(msg);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Now I get a double menu, how do I only get the content within the div formcontent

Comment: @Rails beginner, strictly no idea what double menu you are talking about, what HTML is being returned by your server and what content you want to get inside the formcontent div.

Comment: I only want to get returned the content inside the div with the id formcontent. Else I get all the page returned inside formcontent which I dont want

Comment: @Rails beginner, there's probably something wrong with your server code which returns the entire HTML applying it the layout instead of returning only a partial HTML fragment.

Comment: Is it not possiable with Jquery to only get the content inside the div with the id of formcontent?

Answer (score 1):

fixed code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menuitem input:checkbox').change(function(){
        var form = $(this).parents('form');
        $.ajax({
          type:'get',
          url:form.attr('action'),
          data:form.serialize(),
          success:function(msg){
            $('#formcontent').html(msg);
          }
        });

    $('input[type="submit"]').hide();

    $('.menuitem input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('div.hidediv').addClass('someclass'); // not needed it there is another way of identifying the div later to add to hidediv class again.
            $('div.hidediv').removeClass('hidediv');
        } else {
            $('div.someclass').addClass('hidediv'); 
        }
    });
});
```

Explanation:

1. What is `form` it isn't defined anywhere.
2. If `form` is defined and you do `form.submit();` you would submit the form (not what you want.)
3. You also missing a semicolon after the ajax function.
4. you also used the wrong way of getting inputs of a specific type

Comment: How to addClass hidediv again when the checkbox is unchecked?

Answer (score 0):

The line where you have:

```
url: form.submit;,
```

should be:

```
url: form.attr('action'),
```

So you end up with:

```
    $.ajax({
      type:'get',
      url:form.attr('action'),
      data:form.serialize(),
      success:function(msg){
        $('#formcontent').html(msg);
      }
    })
```

You may also want to change the "type" value to form.attr('method') for consistency.